# Como limitar um input do tipo Number para apenas 3 caracteres?

Tags: html5, number-format

Estou com um problema de uma variável do tipo `integer`, pois o `maxlength=""` só funciona com `string` e preciso barrar, mas é do tipo `Number`. Acho que precisa do javascript, se alguém souber a solução agradeceria.

**Observação:** Já está validado no backend.

**Atualização**: já estou usando `max="999"` e `min="0"`, mas aparece apenas uma mensagem. O usuário pode continuar digitando.

Comment: Você pode fazer  com Jquery.

Comment: se for digitado mais do que deve, o form nao vai dar submit... nao é o bastante?

Comment: para mim é, mas vai falar isso pro analista

Comment: Calma, jóvi. Ainda vai piorar.

Answer (score 7):

Por definição do HTML o elemento `input` com `type="number"` a propriedade `maxlength` é ignorada. como você pode conferir na [documentação da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength)

> **maxlength**
>   If the value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password,
>   tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters
>   (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter. For other control
>   types, it is ignored

*Traduzindo, se o valor do atributo `type` for text, email, search, password, tel, ou url, esse atributo especifica o máximo de caracteres numéricos (em Unicode) que o usuário poderá inserir. Para outros `type`, ele é ignorado.*

Lembrando que você pode justificar ao analista que o form não será submetido, caso o número não tenha sido digitado corretamente.

Uma forma que pode ser feita é utilizando jQuery e `type="text"`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#field").keyup(function() {
      $("#field").val(this.value.match(/[0-9]*/));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="field" type="text" maxlength="3" pattern="([0-9]{3})"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

olá eu tenho este codigo só aceita numeros  e vai até 3 olha ai.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".verifica_numerico").keydown(function(e) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
      // Allow: home, end, left, right
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id_lock" name="id_lock" placeholder="Digite aqui" class="  verifica_numerico " required="" type="text" maxlength="3" size="4">
```

Comment: irei testar agora

Comment: todos os codígos que usei que contem keyCode não da certo :/

Comment: opa, guilherme possivelmente você está com conflito de muitas apis na mesma pagina, lembre-se só pode chamar uma vez o jquery.js se não da pane por que ele se perde.
Se notar você pode rodar o meu exemplo e funciona perfeitamente =D

Answer (score 4):

Existem diversas maneiras de se obter o efeito desejado. 
Mas o ideal mesmo é criar uma validação no [back-end](/questions/tagged/back-end)e caso o input de algum modo tenha sido passado com mais de 3 caracteres, retorne um erro.

Para validação no [front-end](/questions/tagged/front-end) gosto dessa solução, acho bem simples e limpa:

```js
function validar(field) {
  str = field.value;
  if (str.length > 2) {
    field.value = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  }
}

function numerico(evt) {
  var key_code = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.charCode ? evt.charCode : evt.which ? evt.which : void 0;
  if (key_code == 8 || key_code == 9 || key_code == 13 || key_code == 27 || key_code == 46) {
    return true;
  } else if ((key_code >= 35) && (key_code <= 40)) {
    return true
  } else if ((key_code >= 48) && (key_code <= 57)) {
    return true
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="validar(this); return numerico(event);">
```

Comment: Seria, porem tem a possibilidade de um usuário engraçadinho mudar o type do input pela inspeção de elementos, isso só complica um pouco mais a vida do usuário, mas ainda ele pode alterar o script, por isso o ideal mesmo é criar a validação no backend

Comment: Voei no que se refere a "mudar o type do input pela inspeção de elementos," acho que vou fazer essa pergunta pra vc responder, hehehe

Comment: veja: https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohzdWpyfHizb4Jhew/giphy.gif

Comment: já está validado, e mais por questão de visual.

Comment: @GuilhermeOliveira edite sua pergunta e acrescente informações sobe o código que tentou, o que retorno no console, e como esta o seu formulario

Answer (score 4):

> Para limitar um input do **tipo Number** para apenas 3 caracteres e o usuário não conseguir continuar digitando além de 3 caracteres essa função atende.

<sub>OBS: A especificação HTML 5.2 permite explicitamente o caractere 'e' como parte de um número de ponto flutuante em notação exponencial como 1.23e-10.</sub>

> Mas como com apenas 3 caracteres seria impossível usar notação exponencial fiz outra função (update 28/12/2018)

```js
function somenteNumeros(e) {
    var charCode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
    // charCode 8 = backspace   
    // charCode 9 = tab
   if (charCode != 8 && charCode != 9) {
       // charCode 48 equivale a 0   
       // charCode 57 equivale a 9
       var max = 3;
       var num = document.getElementById('num');           
            
       if ((charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)||(num.value.length >= max)) {
          return false;
       }
       
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="num" placeholder="Digite o numero" type="number" onkeypress="return somenteNumeros(event)" required>
```

Comment: Mudei a resposta para evitar que se entre com valores tipo 00000010, 0000000998

Comment: ele aceita apenas a letra 'e' :/

Comment: A especificação HTML 5.2 permite explicitamente o caractere 'e' como parte de um número de ponto flutuante em notação exponencial como 1.23e-10.

Comment: mudei a resposta para não aceitar sinal `-` ou sinal `+`

Comment: Se eu digitar 999 e depois usar o contador padrão do navegador (firefox) eu consigo chegar a casas de 4 dígitos e provavelmente mais.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, eu testei o maxlength aqui e não funcionou, não do jeito que eu esperava. (achei que fosse bloquear a digitação)

Eu fiz uma função js para limitar o número de caracteres:

```
function limitar(el, limit){
    var el = document.querySelector(el);
    el.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
        var input = event.target;
        var toStr = String(input.value);
        if(input.value.length > 3){
            var novo = toStr.slice(0, limit);
            input.value = parseInt(novo);
        }
    });
}
```

**Uso:** no primeiro parâmetro vai o input, em forma de seletor css, e no segundo parâmetro, o limite de caracteres.

**Exemplo:** `limitar('#meuinput', 3);`

Quero deixar claro que não sou nenhum mestre em JS. Ficou uma espécie de "delay" quando o número passa do limite e a função reescreve.

Comment: vlw vou testar agora

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia fazer uso do método [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```js
function limitaTotal (evt) {
    var input = evt.target;
    var value = input.value;

    if (value.length <= 3) {
        return;
    }

    input.value = input.value.substr(0, 3); 
}
```

E para chamar seu código, basta adicionar um `EventListener` no seu `input`:

```
document.getElementById('meu-input').addEventListener('input', limitaTotal)
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('.credit_code').mask('000');    
$('.credit_code').unmask();        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="custom-input form-control credit_code id="credit_code">
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).